# Laravel query builder with the User and Auth

Tags: laravel, query-builder

How to List all rows from a table (agendas) in my DB where records are saved by the connected user.I'm using default Auth from Laravel.

```
public function index ($id = null)

    {
        $agendas = Agenda::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.agendas.index', compact('agendas','users','id'));
    }
```

My controller here.
Need help

Comment: Does agendas table have a user_id column linking it to a record on users table? What's the relationship defined between User and Agenda Model for eg: User hasMany Agenda and Agenda belongsTo User?

Comment: Use Relationships.

Comment: `Agenda::where('id', Auth::user()->id)` is getting an Agenda where the _id_ is the user's id - which is wrong. Please post your relations

Comment: Hello Donkarnash, The Model Agenda and User haven't relationship. Let me try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- agendas table (containing records for Agenda model) has a column `user_id` which references the `id` column on users table
- User hasMany Agenda
- Agenda belongTo User

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function agendas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Agenda::class);
    }

    //... rest of class code
}


class Agenda extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    //... rest of class code
}


public function index($id = null)
{

    $user = User::with('agendas')->findOrFail(auth()->id());

    return view('admin.agendas.index', [
        'user' => $user,
        'agendas' => $user->agendas,
        'id' => $id
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Let me try this and return you as soon as possible. Many Thanks

Comment: Hello Donkarnash, Thanks you very much. It's working

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` model should have a relationship:

```php
public function agendas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Agenda::class);
}
```

In your controller, you could then simplify the use as such:

```php
public function index (Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $agendas = $request->user()->agendas;
    $users = User::all();
    return view('admin.agendas.index', compact('agendas','users','id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna get data related to another data , you have to join those tables together by a field. in this case i guess you have a column in Agenda table named 'user_id'.

you have two way :

1. join tables in your Model.
2. search in Agenda table in your controller

if you want to use joining your tables from model :

```php
// in App\User.php
...
class User ...{
...

    public function Agenda(){
        return $this->hasMany(Agenda::class);
    }
...
}
...
```

then you can access to all of "Agenda" from everywhere like this :
`Auth()->user()->agenda`

if you want to search in table from your controller you can do :
`Agenda::where('id', Auth::user()->id)`

you can read more about eloquent-relationships in : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships